# What's the 4th Prime Directive of RoboCop?

Tags: robocop, robocop-1987

While this question was originated long ago in my mind, it got active again when I was playing 8-bit NES game in an Android NES emulator.

This is screenshot of RoboCop NES game intro:

[image: Robocop Intro]

It says 4 prime directives of RoboCop:

1. Serve the public trust
2. Protect the innocent
3. Uphold the law
4. [Classified]

I want to know this *classified* directive. I've gone thru memories of its few TV shows, games, comics and movie, but I haven't found it. Have you found it in canon?

Comment: At the risk of nitpicking 'prime' means first. There can't be four prime directives.

Comment: @DJClayworth: nitpicking on an old comment but "prime" means "of first importance" or "main". There could be more than one main directive. Also, there could be than one first, as in "the three first persons to answer the question will receive a prize".

Comment: @Taladris:   The usual expression is "first three persons" and I'm not that implies there are more than one "first person".   It implies you are referring to the three people who are first relative to all the other potential groups.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a difference between the movie and the book.

**The movie:**

According to [the script](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/r/robocop-script-transcript-peter-weller.html), Directive 4 is defined as:

> Any attempt to arrest a senior officer of OCP results in shutdown.

These are the words of [Dick Jones](http://robocop.wikia.com/wiki/Dick_Jones), Directive 4's author<sup>1</sup>.

<sub>1. That Dick Jones is the creator of Directive 4 is clear from his words  proceeding the above quote: *"It's a little insurance policy called 'Directive 4.' **My little contribution** to your psychological profile."*</sub>

**The book:**

Page 140:

> DIRECTIVE FOUR: AN OCP PRODUCT SHALL NOT ACT AGAINST OCP'S BEST INTERESTS - AN OCP PRODUCT SHALL NOT ACT AGAINST ANY SENIOR OCP OFFICIAL

Comment: "The book"? What the... :O

Comment: @AndresF.: [it's a great read](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Robocop-Ed-Naha/dp/0440174791)! :)

Answer (score 19):

The fourth directive prevented Robocop from arresting or harming any senior executive of OCP (the company that made Robocop).

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocop#Plot):

> During the confrontation, RoboCop's previously unknown and secret fourth directive, preventing him from arresting or harming any senior executive of OCP, activates, incapacitating him. Jones boasts to RoboCop about adding the directive to his program and even talks about his role in Morton's murder, and then sends an ED-209 against RoboCop.